# Trying to mix multiple colors through shader nodes

Tags: materials, shaders

I'm following a teddy bear tutorial on youtube and I decided to get fancy with my materials and try to copy this texture [image]

However it currently looks like this..
[image]

Here are my shader nodes:
[image]

I think the noise texture is overriding the fabric texture somehow.. Just starting to learn materials and nodes so I'm just messing around. Is there's an easier solution to get to something similar to this texture?

Comment: You're using a normal map image for the height input of the displacement. This doesn't look right. Replace the *Displacement* node with a *Normal Map* node and connect it to the *Normal* input of the *Principled BSDF* node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave it a try. If you use only the normal map and the procedural noise texture it gives you a very muddy texture.

You need to use original texture to "sharpen" it. I've used this one: [Fabric Knitted 005](https://3dtextures.me/2021/08/05/fabric-knitted-005/). The base color has a pattern that I didn't want to use. So I took the ambient occlusion image as a replacement.

Mixed it with your noise texture and added a Musgrave texture to mimic the larger dark and bright areas.

The roughness image of the PBR fabric seems to be pure white. Because I liked to have some variation I inverted and "color ramped" the ambient occlusion image. This way the holes are rough (not shiny) and for the threads, you can have a little sheen.

The result is not completely the same but close to the reference.

[image: shader setup]<sup>The *Mapping* is connected to the *Image Texture*, (it got moved and it's a bit hard to see now)</sup>

[image: long shot]<sup>(The model is not properly UV unwrapped - stitched pattern look)</sup>